# Kafka - count the number of messages stored in a kafka topic for a duration or for a string

Tags: apache-kafka

I have run a program that sends data to a kafka topic. From either the kafka tool or command line, how to find the number of messages send to that topic say for a duration (fromTime to toTime) or for a string in the message ("MOBILE").

What is the command? I get total messages in the topic. But I wanted to know only the count that I send.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use KSQL to achieve it.

Comment: what if the Cloudera version doen't support this.

Comment: You can use kstreams to achieve the same

Comment: Okay. Let me try. Do you have any references